# Boostrap Video Background With Caption Text In Front

Tags: html, css, video

Can someone please help! How to insert caption over the intro video: www.idxforrealestate.com

The code we have is:

```
<div class="holder">

<video width="100%" height="auto" autoplay loop>
  <source src="http://idxforrealestate.com/video/miami-beach.mp4"           type="video/mp4">
</video>

</div>
```

Comment: <div class="holder">

<video width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="" loop="">
  <source src="http://idxforrealestate.com/video/miami-beach.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

</div>

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tdmvwL70/ something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is if you want the caption over your video.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="holder">

  <div id="text_some">Some kind of caption</div>

  <video width="100%" height="auto" autoplay loop>
    <source src="http://idxforrealestate.com/video/miami-beach.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.holder{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:0;
}

#text_some{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  width: 100%;
  height:auto;
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
  font-size: 5vw;
  top: 40%;
}
```

jsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/tax42nar/

Comment: May I ask you one last question... The NAV bar, how do I make it transparent only in the video section, and when it passes the video section or other pages the background turns white... I only want it transparent over the video.

Comment: @sottamogirdor  https://jsfiddle.net/r9khy6ak/ check out the javascript here. it might help you.  Can mark my question right if it helped you. You are welcome.

Comment: I have no understanding of java jquery... jajaja

Comment: @sottamogirdor if paste javascript from this https://jsfiddle.net/e8vaucan/ to your javascript file. It should work. if it doesn't remove this code. Hope this helps